# Grep sorted files in S3 folder

Tags: grep, aws-cli, zcat

I'd like to sort files in S3 folders and then check if files contain a certain string.

When I usually want to grep a file I do the following:

```
aws s3 cp s3://s3bucket/location/file.csv.gz - | zcat | grep 'string_to_find'
```

I see I can sort files like this:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 \
--bucket s3bucket \
--prefix location \
--query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents,&LastModified))'
```

Tried something like this so far but got broken pipe:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 \
--bucket s3bucket \
--prefix location \
--query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents,&LastModified))' | cp - | zcat | grep 'string_to_find'
```

Comment: `xargs` might help.

Comment: thanks Cyrus, how would that work? not familiar with xargs in terminal. should that be within the cp? tried this but didn't work ```xargs -I % cp -```

Comment: Side-note: You are effectively downloading each file but throwing away the results, so if you are going to do repeated searches you would be better-off doing an `aws s3 sync` to copy the files locally and then search them locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify which fields to output and force them into text-only:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 \
--bucket s3bucket \
--prefix location \
--query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents,&LastModified))[].[Key]' \
--output text
```

Basically, the `sort_by` and `reverse` output the `Contents` array, and this extracts the `Key` element. I put `[Key]` in square brackets to force each result onto its own line.